# Apache is running but i cannot connect to local host

Tags: apache, xampp

I have installed `xampp` on windows 8 and `apache` could not start and connect on port 80.
I changed the port to 1337 on the `httpd.conf`. Apache now starts on `xampp` and shows that it is running on port 1137 and 443 but when i type localhost on Google chrome i getan error message stating Google chrome could not connect to localhost.
can somebody help me please.

Answer (score 1):

since you changed the port from standardport 80 you have to type localhost:1137

Answer (score 1):

When you type

```
http://localhost
```

on your browser, it connects to port 80 by default. and

```
https://localhost
```

will connect to port 443 by default. Since you've changed the port numbers, you have to use

```
localhost:1137
```

or

```
https://localhost
```

in your browser.